# $\tt ifft()$ function - absolute vs real form

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-domain, time-domain

I have multiple files from an experiment in frequency-domain that I would like to use `ifft()` function to convert to the time domain in R to apply signal processing techniques.

My question is about the principle of this conversion:
at the moment my frequency values are non-complex numbers (I believe they are in their absolute form).

- So, to convert these columns using `ifft()` function, should I use the absolute values or there is a way break these values down to the complex form and then do `ifft()` on those?
- My other question is, which form (absolute or real) is the best form to save my data in the ***time domain*** for further signal processing techniques?

If this helps, my data looks like this:

```
| Time (s)| 0.0000 |0.000164|... 
|:--------|--------|:-------|:-------
| 1.52kHz |  2747  |  350   |...
| 3.05kHz |  2996  |  420   |...
| 4.57kHz |  4078  |  300   |...
|   ...   |  ...   |  ...   |...
```

Total of $513$ rows $\times$ $122041$ cols, sampling frequency of $1562.5\textrm{ kHz}$.

Comment: I doubt that you can reproduce the exact time domain signal from this table. It looks like a spectrogram and these cannot be inverted to yield the original time-domain signal (you're missing the phase information). In general, saving the absolute value loses information, compared to real/imaginary representation. The question is, why you need to get the time-domain function. Maybe, if you describe what kind of signal processing you want to do, we can help doing it with the data you have available?

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé Thanks for your comprehensive answer. This data is from an electrostatic sensor that I was hoping to apply some signal processing techniques (such as wavelet, STFT or even analysing it in the time domain).

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé Also, what's the best way to average the values for each second in the frequency spectrum (at the moment the interval is 0.000164s)? I wonder if averaging is my best option or there is a better way to do what I would like to do?

Comment: This is an old problem: control engineers estimate the poles/zeros all the time.  There are conditional solutions: From: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04861.pdf   "PHASE retrieval is a longstanding problem in many fields of physics and applied sciences [1], [2], [3], [4]. Sufficient conditions ensuring that the phase of the signal and hence
the full E(t) can be reconstructed from the knowledge of
the intensity profile only |E(t)|^2 are well known [2], [3],[5], [6]"  But be aware that this will give a model that matches the data; but might not be the "right" model.

Comment: To continue: this gives the phase on the imaginary axis where you can do a numerical/symbolic inverse transform accurately if 1) All of the poles are in the LHP and the network goes to 0 exponentially (? as I recall) at infinity.